# Can I have multiple ApexMocks startStubbing()-stopStubbing() Pairs in same testmethod?

Tags: apexmock

All the [examples, e.g.](https://andyinthecloud.com/2015/03/29/unit-testing-apex-enterprise-patterns-and-apexmocks-part-2/) for ApexMocks use a single wrapper:

```
mocks.startStubbing();
... your stub returns here
mocks.stopStubbing();
```

But what happens if your testmethod involves multiple startStubbing()-stopStubbing() pairs?  Are the mocked returns additive or smashing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple test method illustrates that

- for a given stubbed method/matcher, if the method stub is used twice, the last one wins
- multiple startStubbing()-stopStubbing() wrappers are additive

  ```
  static void testAdditiveMocks() {
      fflib_ApexMocks mocks = new fflib_ApexMocks();

      Contact[] mockContactsA = new List<Contact> {
              new Contact(Id = fflib_IDGenerator.generate(Contact.SObjectType),
                          Lastname = 'mockA')
      };
      Contact[] mockContactsB = new List<Contact> {
              new Contact(Id = fflib_IDGenerator.generate(Contact.SObjectType), 
                          Lastname = 'mockB')
      };

      // Given mock selector
      ContactsSelector mockContactsSelector = (ContactsSelector) mocks.mock(ContactsSelector.class);

      // First start-stop Stubbing
      mocks.startStubbing();
      mocks.when(mockContactsSelector.SObjectType()).thenReturn(Contact.SObjectType);
      mocks.when(mockContactsSelector
              .selectById((Set<Id>)fflib_Match.anyObject()))
              .thenReturn(mockContactsA);
      //  add same mock return for same method/matcher
      mocks.when(mockContactsSelector
              .selectById((Set<Id>)fflib_Match.anyObject()))
              .thenReturn(mockContactsB);
      mocks.stopStubbing();

      Id arbitraryId = fflib_IDGenerator.generate(Contact.SObjectType);

      // Second start stubbing: a different selector method
      mocks.startStubbing();
      mocks.when(mockContactsSelector.SObjectType()).thenReturn(Contact.SObjectType);
      mocks.when(mockContactsSelector.selectAll())
              .thenReturn(mockContactsA);
      mocks.stopStubbing();

      // Given mocks injected
      Application.Selector.setMock(mockContactsSelector);

      // When test the mocks
      System.assertEquals(mockContactsB,ContactsSelector.newInstance()
              .selectById(new Set<Id> {arbitraryId}));
      System.assertEquals(mockContactsA,ContactsSelector.newInstance()
              .selectAll());
  }
  ```

**Analysis**

- The first assert that relies on a mock `selectById()` returns the list mockContactsB as that was the **last** stubbed return for the method `selectById()` using matcher `fflib_Match.anyObject()`
- The second assert returns the mocked result for `selectAll()` even though it was stubbed in a second start-stop stubbing pair for the same ContactsSelector instance.

**Why is this useful?**
It allows you to use composition of mock stubbing in construction of testmethods for mix-and-match scenarios when you need to mock multiple selectors or services in various combinations.

*Reminder*: be sure to inject your mocks into your factory that provides runtime instances of the class to the code under test - here, I'm using fflib_Application for that purpose as outline in [Andrew Fawcett's blog on Unit testing and Enterprise Patterns](https://andyinthecloud.com/2015/03/29/unit-testing-apex-enterprise-patterns-and-apexmocks-part-2/)